# How to Get WEEKOFYEAR with php?

Tags: php, sql

I need to fatch WEEKOFYEAR number from this php code but it's not working, please help to make it works
I need use "UTC_DATE()"

```
 <?php

    $r11 = mysql_query("SELECT WEEKOFYEAR()  FROM `users`");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($r11);
    $r11=$result['WEEKOFYEAR()'];
    echo $r11;

    }
    else{
    echo("error");
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `WEEKOFYEAR` requires a date argument which is missing here. You should check your query errors rather than just showing the message "error" while debugging.

Comment: yes missing because I need use UTC_DATE() as date  string and dont know how to do this...

Comment: `WEEKOFYEAR(UTC_DATE())` and use @scaisEdge 's solution to give an alias to the column. Also remove `FROM users` you don't need it at all.

Comment: Why not doing it in PHP? `print date('W');` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, as [they were removed from PHP 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

use  an alias  for function name

```
    $r11 = mysql_query("SELECT WEEKOFYEAR()  as WEEK_OF_YEAR FROM `users`");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($r11);
    $r11=$result['WEEK_OF_YEAR'];
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, as [they were removed from PHP 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)